# Subscription made but zero events received

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Created a subscription to a mailbox but events are not fired when mails are received on the mailbox. Is the Graph mail subscription feature not very repayable?

I did this exact thing a couple of weeks ago in prototype codebase and it worked perfectly. Now I'm implementing in production code and it no longer seems to work.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = CreateGraphClient();

var subscription = new Subscription()
{
    ChangeType = "created",
    NotificationUrl = callbackUrl,
    Resource = string.Format("/users/{0}/mailFolders/inbox/messages", mailAccount),
    ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(4230),
};

var result = graphClient.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(subscription).Result;
```

No exception is thrown and we register that the initial call to the NotificationUrl is actually performed.

What is going on??!?

Comment: What is your prototyping codebase? Do you mean you took it out of a runnable codebase and put it in your code? Please double check some environment configuration, code logic and whether your email and verification are correct. Here is a [complete example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample) that might help you.

Comment: Found the problem. Prototype reads Query string. In production it uses [FromQuery]. Apparently MS Graph will only supply a validationToken string parameter in the initial call to the callback when registering the subscription. When Graph then issues an event on received email it does not supply a validationToken parameter and so ASP.NET Core rejects the request and my code is never reached. By just making a blank Get() and reading the QueryString manually it works now.

Comment: Your supplied example use a default value for validationToken parameter. I gotta remember that trick on FromQuery marked params.

[FromQuery] string validationToken = null

Comment: I mean a blank Post( ) not Get( ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. I put a ([FromQuery] string validationToken) on the Post function.

This means that if a client is calling this Post function without a validationToken parameter they will get an error before the code is even reached.

Either set a default value of null on the parameter or do not add a parameter to the function definition and just read the query string from code instead.

```
public IActionResult Post([FromQuery] string? validationToken = null)
```